# I want to add user input value ($itm_sld) + Existing value (itm_sld)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add user input value **`($itm_sld)` + Existing value `itm_sld`**
I use this code

```
<?php
$sql="UPDATE itm_tot 
SET itm_sld = itm_sld + '$itm_sld'
WHERE itm_no='$itm_no'"; ?>
```

But the new value is UPDATED  by **`itm_sld = itm_sld + (itm_sld + '$itm_sld')`**

What should i do to update **`itm_sld`** by **`(itm_sld + '$itm_sld')`**

Thanks....

Comment: why not printing the value of $itm_sld and see if the error is from it or from DB

Comment: what is the type of itm_sld field in your database?

Comment: no there is no errors from it or DB...

Answer (score 0):

Check  [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) method for string concatenation.